# Sentry upgrade error

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, sentry

I'm transferring an existing Sentry install to a new machine, so my database isn't clean (i.e. just restored from a backup of the old one).

When I run `$ sentry upgrade`, I get the error:

```
Running migrations for django:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > django:0001_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "djkombu_queue" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
The error was: relation "djkombu_queue" already exists

Error in migration: django:0001_initial

# Traceback...

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "djkombu_queue" already exists
```

Comment: django migration is trying to create a table which already exists in the target database. Did you maybe restore the database directly, then run a process that would try to migrate it, thereby causing this collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrading/index.html#conflicts-with-kombu-transport-django

Apparently kombu recently added support for South, and that causes this error because your running a version from before it used South.

The solution is to simply run:

```
sentry migrate kombu.transport.django 0001 --fake
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume after the fake migrate, I should run the upgrade command again right?

Comment: Yes, that just makes it ignore the migration. You still need to upgrade.